# Proving $\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n{x_i}}{(\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i})^n}\leq\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n{(1+x_i)}}{( \sum_{i=1}^n{(1+x_i)})^n}$ for positive real $x_i$

Tags: inequality

For every $x_i\in \mathbb{R}$, $x_i>0$, prove that
$$
\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n{x_i}}{\left( \sum_{i=1}^n{x_i} \right) ^n}\leq \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n{\left( 1+x_i \right)}}{\left( \sum_{i=1}^n{\left( 1+x_i \right)} \right) ^n}
$$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I upvoted this so that you can improve your post

Comment: I'll upvote it *if* the question is improved.

Comment: @SaltedFishKing  There is  nice solution of your problem. Show your attempts and I'll show my solution.

Comment: My edit was deleted. I post it again as comments since we should add some relevant information to avoid being an isolated problem. Relevant problem: Ky Fan inequality, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ky_Fan_inequality. If $x_i \in [0, 1/2], i=1, 2, \cdots, n$, then
$\frac{(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i)^{1/n}}{(\prod_{i=1}^n (1-x_i))^{1/n}}
\le \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (1-x_i)}$. Proof: $x \mapsto \ln \frac{x}{1-x}$ is concave on $(0, 1/2]$.
Then apply Jensen's inequality to get the desired result. See wikipedia page for details. The OP can be proved in a similar manner.

Comment: @RiverLi I rolled back your edit because I thought it was going against the new [guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32402/guidelines-for-context-edits-and-rewrites) for context edits, although I admit it is borderline (since what you wanted to add is not exactly an attempt).

Comment: @ArnaudD.  Does this rule apply: "You can add in relevant definitions, theorems, or simple background and motivation"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite our inequality in the following form.
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x_k}\right)}{n}\geq\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k}{n}}\right).$$
Now we see that it's just Jensen for the convex function $f(x)=\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$ for $x>0$.