# Proving that $\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n{x_i}}{(\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i})^n}\leq\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n{(1+x_i)}}{( \sum_{i=1}^n{(1+x_i)})^n}$ for positive real $x_i$

Tags: inequality

For every positive real $x_i$, prove that

$$\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n{x_i}}{\left( \sum_{i=1}^n{x_i} \right) ^n}\leq \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n{\left( 1+x_i \right)}}{\left( \sum_{i=1}^n{\left( 1+x_i \right)} \right) ^n}$$

I think in order to prove it, we need to use Jensen so that I transform this origin inequality to
$$
\frac{\left( \sum_{i=1}^n{\left( 1+x_i \right)} \right) ^n}{\left( \sum_{i=1}^n{x_i} \right) ^n}\le \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n{\left( 1+x_i \right)}}{\prod_{i=1}^n{x_i}}
$$
then
$$\left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i+n}}{\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i}} \right) ^n\leqslant \prod_{i=1}^n{\frac{1+x_i}{x_i}}$$

after that, I use ln to simplify and I get

$$n\ln \left( 1+\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i}} \right) \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n{\left( 1+\frac{1}{x_i} \right)}$$

then keep going and I get
$$\ln \left( 1+\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i}} \right) \leqslant 1+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{1}{x_i}}}{n} $$
then how can an apply Jensen to this inequality

Comment: This is Ky-Fan's inequality. If you google it, you find many proofs. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ky_Fan_inequality

Comment: On the next to last inequality, the right-hand side should be $\sum\ln(1+1/x_i)$, you forgot the $ln$. With that in place it's just Jensen's inequality applied to $\ln(1+x)$.

Comment: @Andreas  The question was posted some days ago. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3879249/proving-frac-prod-i-1nx-i-sum-i-1nx-in-leq-frac-prod-i-1n#comment8008768_3879249